# wildmenu doesn't appear for :find when the current buffer is a .js file

Tags: neovim

I'm having a problem with nvim.

If I load a file, eg x.txt, x.html, or x.cs, then (in normal mode) type in ":find <tab>" I get a wildmenu of filenames.

However, if the file is a .js file, then typing in ":find <tab>" in normal mode does nothing. Typing in ":color <tab>" DOES show a list of colorschemes however, so wildmenu is working, but not for :find.

I'm at a loss as to why :find isn't working for .js files.

Any tips on where to look?

Comment: javascript.vim was setting omnifunc. I'm not sure what that does but removing that setting causes :find to work.